# Tracking events on parts of website - Google Analytics?

Tags: events, google-analytics, tracking

I'm building a single page ad-free portfolio-type website using jquery Isotope. I would like to track how often each project (Isotope element - div with text and a slideshow in it) will be clicked to be able to compare project popularity. Can this be done with Google Analytics? Is that the best tool for that purpose or are there simpler/better/other ones? The provider provides a tool called Webalizer, but that does not allow me to hook up each project element. Google Analytics gives me only information regarding the entire site, not its parts. Thanks for any advice...

**EDIT** I'm reasonably good with jquery, maybe there's a simple programmatic solution?

Answer (score 0):

This works, placed in the click function assigned to all items (in my case a click function assigned to a div inside the items); now, one can Google track which Isotope .item (e.g. project, image or slideshow, etc.) is more popular than others. Maybe this helps others...

```
var clicked = $(this).parent().data('item');
//console.log(clicked); to see if an item's data attribute gets read
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Item', 'Viewed', clicked, null, false]);
//_trackEvent(category (Event Name), action (Event Type), opt_label (Event Label), opt_value, opt_noninteraction) synopsis differs in google's guide and Google Analytics Tracking Code Debugger console output
```